# Why does my generated databinding class throw a ClassCastException for my compound view?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I make a compound view, and I inflate it from xml, like so:

```
class CompoundView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_layout, this)
    }
```

But then I try to use this class in the XML layout of a Fragment using Databinding. This layout file is called `my_other_layout`. When this Fragment starts, the app crashes with a cryptic `ClassCastException`.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1):

After tearing much of my hair out, I realise the issue is that I have 2 views, in 2 different XML layout files, with the same id.

`my_layout` contains a view called `myView`, and `my_other_layout` also contains a different view called `myView`.

And apparently databinding can't differentiate between these ids, hence trying to cast one of the views into the type of the other.

Comment: wow, thanks for sharing, I don't think I would ever have figured that out